# CFBundleExecutableKey does not contain a bundle executable

Tags: react-native, info.plist, cfbundleidentifier

I am facing this issue in React native iOS after archiving the project and uploading it:

```
Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at 'Payload/dummy.app/AccessibilityResources.bundle' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue. (ID: 243b1aea-2032-48d3-8b0b-7a13b4c2f5e9
```

I am getting from very long time, despite of numerous attempt and applying different methods still getting this error:

```
"react-native":  "0.71.2",
"macOS": "12.5",
"IOS target", 
"xcode-version": "14.1 (14B47b)"
```

I have tried solutions [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/80534)
but none of them worked please help me figuring out this issue.

Comment: i have the same problem, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have had exact this issue for months. I have resolved it by:

1. Remove node-modules folder, yarn.lock file.
2. Remove Pods folder, pod.lock file.
3. Run yarn install.
4. Run npx pod-install.
5. Open XCode, clean the project (CMD + K). Archive again.

**=> Upload successfully now**.